# Flutter automate screen scrolling of keyboard size when keyboard appears in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

I want same way so that when keyboard appears on screen when user clicks on TextField, screen should be **animate up** of by size of keyboard **automatically not manually.**

If anybody know any way it is really helpful..

**Note :**
Widgets in column are not occupying complete screen

```
child: SingleChildScrollView(

child : Padding(
              padding:  EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
......
```

I done this with MediaQuery but not animating up but when keyboard goes it animating down properly.
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, added already

Comment: what is the parent widget of `SingleChildScrollView` ?

Answer (score 0):

by set padding botttom with `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom)` means that we are add padding bottom with same height with keyboard.

I guess there are some widget as before the `SingleChildScrollView`. if you are set the padding on children, padding will be add only to the children. so it cant automatically set new padding.

Solution: Use the padding on top of widget tree.

if there is any widget before SinglechildScrollView, set the padding there.

```
Padding(
   padding:  EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
   child: SingleChildScrollView(
     child: Column(
    ....
```